# How to show clean log due to expired in redis container

Tags: redis

I want to find a solution for showing the cleaned cache when they are expired in redis container. Have any way to solve it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how do I know a specific key has expired from Redis - you can use Keyspace notifications and listen for any events and log.

https://redis.io/topics/notifications

One a listener session

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> config set notify-keyspace-events KEex
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> psubscribe '__key*__:*'
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "psubscribe"
2) "__key*__:*"
3) (integer) 1
#### After waiting for a while...
1) "pmessage"
2) "__key*__:*"
3) "__keyspace@0__:foo"
4) "expired"
1) "pmessage"
2) "__key*__:*"
3) "__keyevent@0__:expired"
4) "foo"
```

Then create a key with an expiration

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set foo bar EX 2
OK
```

Otherwise you can watch the # of keys expired or evicted using various open source observability tools like Prometheus.

Comment: Yeah, it works with me